# Send html in email with Catalyst and Catalyst::Plugin::Email

Tags: plugins, html-email, catalyst

I have been reading about Catalyst framework and I am trying to send an email with HTML content without success.

I tried to use Catalyst::Plugin::Email, just as the example [here](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst%3a%3aView%3a%3aTT). The email is sent, but all the content is showed in plain text.

```
sub send_email : Local {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;

    $c->email(
      header => [
        To      => 'me@localhost',
        Subject => 'A TT Email',
      ],
      body => $c->view('Web')->render($c, 'email.tt', {
          additional_template_paths => [ $c->config->{root} . '/email_templates'],
          email_tmpl_param1 => 'foo'
        }
      ),
    );
    # Redirect or display a message
}
```

I also read about [Catalyst::View::Email::Template](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst%3a%3aHelper%3a%3aView%3a%3aEmail%3a%3aTemplate), but I chouldn't install it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now available to send HTML emails with Catalyst::Plugin::Email. From documentation:

"email() accepts the same arguments as Email::MIME::Creator's create()."

Looking into Email::MIME::Creator, the create method structure is:

```
my $single = Email::MIME->create(
    header_str => [ ... ],
    body_str   => '...',
    attributes => { ... },
);

my $multi = Email::MIME->create(
    header_str => [ ... ],
    parts      => [ ... ],
    attributes => { ... },
);
```

"Back to attributes. The hash keys correspond directly to methods or modifying a message from Email::MIME::Modifier. The allowed keys are: content_type, charset, name, format, boundary, encoding, disposition, and filename. They will be mapped to "$attr_set" for message modification."

This is the code it is working:

```
sub send_email : Local {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;

    $c->email(
      header => [
        To      => 'me@localhost',
        Subject => 'A TT Email',
      ],
      body => $c->view('Web')->render($c, 'email.tt', {
          additional_template_paths => [ $c->config->{root} . '/email_templates'],
          email_tmpl_param1 => 'foo'
        }
      ),
      attributes => {
        content_type => 'text/html',
        charset => 'utf-8'
      },
    );

    # Redirect or display a message
}
```